# HDFS Directory as parameter in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm having problems with the Spark Streaming example:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/examples/HdfsWordCount.scala

When I try to launch it using SBT

```
run local /user/dir/subdir/
```

I get this exception

```
[info] Running org.apache.spark.streaming.examples.HdfsWordCount local /user/dir/subdir/
14/04/21 18:45:55 INFO StreamingExamples: Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
14/04/21 18:45:55 INFO StreamingExamples: Setting log level to [WARN] for streaming example. To override add a custom log4j.properties to the classpath.
14/04/21 18:45:55 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ubuntu resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.4.4.6 instead (on interface eth0)
14/04/21 18:45:55 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
14/04/21 18:45:57 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/04/21 18:46:00 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1398098760000 ms
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/dir/subdir/ does not exist
```

I'm sure the directory exists on Hadoop fs and I even copied a file there. 
Is there some kind of input formatting I'm not aware of?

Comment: You are right, wrong link. Now should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to my answer.
The correct way to input a hdfs directory is this, atleast in my case:

```
run local hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dir/subdir/
```

I've found this in Spark Documentation:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#running-alongside-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look at your core-site.xml file inside hadoop. It must have a property with the default path

```
<configuration>
    <property>
          <name>fs.default.name</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```